# HoloLens DirectX C# app: Simplest way to show a message box from immersive view?

Tags: c#, directx, hololens

Is there any easy way to show a message box from an immersive view of my application?

My app was created using the "Holographic DirectX 11 App (Universal Windows)" template.

It works as a hologram (in an immersive view).

It uses the SharpDX library.

I know I can create XAML UI and temporarily switch to the 2D mode, but this seems to be a lot work...